# Why an empty input value equal to true?

Tags: javascript, angular, if-statement, input, null

This code is suppose to execute oninput if the input is equal to the answer.
Instead, if i have a multiplication problem that equals 0, once i delete the answer from the previous multiplcation problem (leaving the input empty), the result comes back true and executes the if statement. How can i prevent this?

```
 ngOnInit() { this.multiply(); }
  f1 =  0;
  f2 =  0;
  answer:number = 0;
  input:number = 0;
 
  multiply():void{
    this.f1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    this.f2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);

    this.answer = this.f1 * this.f2;

    console.log(this.answer);
  }

  checkAnswer(event){
      this.input = event.target.value;

      if(this.input == this.answer){
        console.log(this.input + " " + "is correct!");

        this.multiply();
      } else{
        console.log(this.input + " " + "is incorrect" + " "  + this.answer);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `this.input = event.target.value.trim();`

Comment: try to use "===" instead of "=="
i updated the below answer to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reset the input value if, if statement is true.

`event.target.value = null;`

Prevents the user from firing the input event to clear the input. Thus not having to run checkAnswer function if this.answer === 0 and this.input === " ";

Answer (score 1):

### Use `===` instead of `==`

So your if statement should be

```
if(this.input === this.answer){
```

**Explanation:**

- `==` only compares the `value` and not `datatype`
- `===` compares the value and datatype both

**Examples:**

- `'' == 0 => true` (true because `==` only checks the value)
- `'' === 0 => false`
  (false because `===` checks both the value and its datatype)

[Here, you can read about the difference between `==` and `===`](https://www.guru99.com/difference-equality-strict-operator-javascript.html#:%7E:text=%3D%20Vs%20%3D%3D%20VS%20%3D%3D%3D%20in%20JavaScript,-Here%20are%20the&text=%3D%3D%20in%20JavaScript%20is%20used,datatype%20and%20compares%20two%20values.&text=It%20returns%20true%20only%20if,same%20for%20the%20two%20variables.)

Comment: I tried "===" but it did not work. It comes back false even if the answer is correct.

Comment: @Creatif_IV Can you please console.log both your answer and input value and check whether they are same or not? Please also mention both values here.

Comment: Ok, i get it now,.I console.log(typeof this.input). The input is being identified as a string. 0 and "  "(an empty string) return "true".Weird.